# Найти все связанные таблицы по наличию одновременно двух наименований столбцов

Tags: sql, oracle

Возникла, популярная задача, найти к таблице все связанные с ней таблицы. В базе созданы не все констрейты. 
сделал вот такой запрос

```
    SELECT
    DISTINCT t1.table_name table1,
    t2.table_name table2,
    t1.column_name column1,
    t2.column_name column2,
    t1.owner own
FROM
    dba_tab_columns t1,
    dba_tab_columns t2
WHERE
    t1.column_name = t2.column_name
    AND t1.table_name = 'my_table_name'
    AND t1.table_name <> t2.table_name
    AND t2.table_name IN (
    SELECT
        table_name
    FROM
        dba_tables)
```

Подскажите, что добавить, или помогите составить запрос, который найдет связанные таблицы по наименованиям столбцов, но как бы по составному ключу т.е. по одновременному совпадению в таблицах двух и более столбцов. 
в ином случае я получаю связанные таблицы но и те, которые совпадают только по одному полю.

пс
наименования столбцов в условие WHERE добавлять пробовал, не помогло. 
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Схематично

```
SELECT t1.table_name, t2.table_name
FROM dba_tab_columns t1,
     dba_tab_columns t2
WHERE t1.table_name != t2.table_name
  AND t1.column_name = t2.column_name
GROUP BY t1.table_name, t2.table_name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Выведет все пары таблиц такие, что у них в структуре имеется как минимум два одноименных поля. Если нужно, добавьте доп. условия (скажем, вывести парные только для одной таблицы - `WHERE t1.table_name = 'some name'`).

Comment: Спасибо, большое.